Using prospector for jwst data
I am working with JWST data. I want to estimate the redshift of the sources I have identified with SEXtractor with the help of prospector. Can somebody guide me in this?

My question is off topic: what is a "prospector".

Prospector is a package to conduct principled inference of stellar population properties from photometric and/or spectroscopic data using flexible models. One can use it to estimate redshift of sources by fitting an SED.

The initial data arrives on Earth from JWT. Where can I watch them? I would like to see the structure and what they look like in general.

The initial JWST data can be downloaded from MAST(Mikulski Archive for Space Telescopes), I have an extracted source list with magnitudes and errors, and want to exctarct redshift from such a catalogue

Then first we need to understand how a prospector works. Surely there must be some examples. Perhaps you can get some information from here https://prospect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/acba99/pdf https://github.com/bd-j/prospector/blob/main/doc/quickstart.rst

I have gone through them and their manual , what we need is a parameter_file.py which contains all the details of fitting and all.

yes, we now need to figure out how this file is structured.

So it basically needs two functions build_obs() and build_model(), in which build_obs() is just creating a dictionary of the flux in units of maggies. The trouble is in the part of build_model() and then creating the whole file

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
